# Java classpath confusion

Tags: java, deployment, classpath

I wrote and tested a small Java program using Eclipse.  I'm now trying to deploy it on a Windows 7 box and Java cannot find the class.  I copied the class file to C:\dxtester\classes.  I'm trying to run it from the dxtester directory with: `C:\dxtester>java -classpath classes;. dxtester`

This produces this exception which I think I understand.  Java examined the class file and is prompting me to provide the fully qualified name.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dxtester (wrong name:
 dxtester/dxtester)
```

If I use the FQN I get

```
C:\dxtester>java -classpath classes;. dxtester.dxtester
Error: Could not find or load main class dxtester.dxtester
```

The application is a simple test driver where everything is done in main().

```
package dxtester;
public class dxtester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

This seemed like an extremely simple thing to do but I'm completely baffled.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your class is called `dxtester` and is also in a package called `dxtester`, but you haven't compiled it appropriately to be in the right directory. Ideally, you should use different names to start with (`dxtester` doesn't follow Java naming conventions, for example) and make sure the file hierarchy follows the package hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi!  The problem was not the compilation but the deployment.  The deploy script did not create the correct dxtester directory for the class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your current directory is `dxtester`;
2. in this directory you have `dxtester.class` (I presume);
3. your classpath is the current directory.

This setup is wrong: your classpath must be the base directory such that package names correspond to its subdirectories. In your case you should `cd` to `C:\` and repeat the command; ideally, however, you will have your package structure in a dedicated directory instead of the root.

I should also mention that class names should be in `CamelCase`.